# MYSQL update or insert with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, upsert

I need to update a record in the database, but I don't know if that record already exists. If it exists, update it, else insert it. Now I came up with this code:

```
1: <?php
2: $query = "UPDATE user_meta SET active = '0' WHERE user_id = '125'";
3: $mysqli->query($query);
4: 
5: if($mysqli->affected_rows == 0){
6:     $query = "INSERT INTO user_meta (user_id, active) VALUES ('125', 0)";
7:     $mysqli->query($query);
8: }
```

The table:

```
CREATE TABLE `user_meta` (
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `user_id` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

This code is working fine for me, but it actually generates an error which I neglect.

The problem is in this line `5`. The affected_rows is `0` if nothing is changed, even if the record already exists. But this will trigger the INSERT statement. This one fails because the user_id field is unique, now I'm ignoring this so my code is working fine.

But is this the way to go? 
Or should I do first a select and than update or insert?

Comment: make the user_id int and not string and check

Comment: Before performing insert or update, simply fire one `SELECT query to get count for this user id`. If count is 1 then perform update else perform insert.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can solve this using `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY`

Using this method will be transactionally safe, as MySQL is handling it in one implicit transaction.  Your current method allows a split moment where two concurrent requests could interfere with one another.

Assuming you're on MySQL 5.7: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Your query would look like this:

```
INSERT INTO user_meta SET user_id = 125, active = 0
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE active = 0
```

---

**Update:**
Just to elaborate on why your current method is transactionally *unsafe*, imagine two concurrent requests executing in parallel.

1. Request 1 attempts an update, sees 0 affected rows.
2. Request 2 attempts an update, sees 0 affected rows.
3. Request 1 inserts a new record.
4. Request 2 inserts a new record.

Whether you *explicitly* start and complete a transaction, or whether you *implicitly* do (e.g. through `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY`) MySQL will take the responsibility for ensuring that the aforementioned faulty scenario doesn't occur by blocking a second request until the first finishes.

Answer (score 5):

MySQL has a built-in solution for this - the [`on duplicate key update`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) clause:

```
INSERT INTO user_meta (user_id, active) 
VALUES (125, 0)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE active = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

use mysql `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` to check the record is already exist in the db or not. Your table must have a column having `unique` type for this. Here your `user_id` column is unique type. Check the documention [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

```
INSERT INTO user_meta (user_id, active) 
VALUES (125, 0)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE active = 0
```